# What is the fastest java file copy method with progress monitoring?

Tags: java, file, copy, nio, unc

I'm working on a file copying application which is used to copy files from client machine to a network folder (UNC path). Client and network folder are connected using a 10Gbps connection. Traditional Stream/Buffer mechanism could only use up to 250Mbps. That is why I started using NIO methods. Both `Files.copy()` and `transferFrom()` methods could use upto 6Gbps bandwidth which is sufficient for now. But the problem is both these methods doesn't provide progress. I must need to display the file copying progress in my application.

Then I found `ReadableByteChannel` interface to track the upload progress. But after implementing this, upload speed dropped to 100Mbps. Not sure if I didn't implement it correctly.

OS level copying (Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V) works with 6Gbps bandwidth utilization. How to achieve the same with Java method with progress monitoring?

```
public class AppTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File source = new File(args[0]);
        File dest = new File(args[1] + File.separator + source.getName());
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            if (args[2].equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
                copyUsingStream(source, dest, args.length > 3 ? Integer.parseInt(args[3]) : 32 * 1024);
            } else if (args[2].equalsIgnoreCase("fp")) {
                copyUsingFileChannelWithProgress(source, dest);
            } else if (args[2].equalsIgnoreCase("f")){
                copyUsingFileChannels(source, dest);
            } else if (args[2].equalsIgnoreCase("j")) {
                copyUsingFilescopy(source, dest);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Unknown copy option.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Completed in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    }

    private static void copyUsingStream(File source, File dest, int buf_size) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Copying using feeder code...");
        System.out.println("Buffer Size : " + buf_size);
        FileInputStream sourceFileIS = new FileInputStream(source);
        FileOutputStream srvrFileOutStrm = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        byte[] buf = new byte[buf_size];
        int dataReadLen;
        while ((dataReadLen = sourceFileIS.read(buf)) > 0) {
            srvrFileOutStrm.write(buf, 0, dataReadLen);
        }
        srvrFileOutStrm.close();
        sourceFileIS.close();
    }

    private static void copyUsingFileChannels(File source, File dest)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Copying using filechannel...");
        FileChannel inputChannel = null;
        FileChannel outputChannel = null;
        try {
            inputChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
            outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(dest).getChannel();
            outputChannel.transferFrom(inputChannel, 0, inputChannel.size());
        } finally {
            inputChannel.close();
            outputChannel.close();
        }
    }

    private static void copyUsingFilescopy(File source, File dest) throws IOException{
        Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());
    }

    interface ProgressCallBack {

        public void callback(CallbackByteChannel rbc, double progress);
    }

    static class CallbackByteChannel implements ReadableByteChannel {

        ProgressCallBack delegate;
        long size;
        ReadableByteChannel rbc;
        long sizeRead;

        CallbackByteChannel(ReadableByteChannel rbc, long sizeRead, long expectedSize, ProgressCallBack delegate) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
            this.sizeRead = sizeRead;
            this.size = expectedSize;
            this.rbc = rbc;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            rbc.close();
        }

        public long getReadSoFar() {
            return sizeRead;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isOpen() {
            return rbc.isOpen();
        }

        @Override
        public int read(ByteBuffer bb) throws IOException {
            int n;
            double progress;
            if ((n = rbc.read(bb)) > 0) {
                sizeRead += n;
                progress = size > 0 ? (double) sizeRead / (double) size * 100.0 : -1.0;
                delegate.callback(this, progress);
            }
            return n;
        }
    }

    private static void copyUsingFileChannelWithProgress(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
        ProgressCallBack progressCallBack = new ProgressCallBack() {

            @Override
            public void callback(CallbackByteChannel rbc, double progress) {
//                            publish((int)progress);
            }
        };
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        FileChannel sourceChannel = null;
        sourceChannel = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = new CallbackByteChannel(sourceChannel, 0, sourceFile.length(), progressCallBack);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, sourceFile.length());
        if (sourceChannel.isOpen()) {
            sourceChannel.close();
        }
        fos.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `transferFrom()` in a loop with a large chunk size that is still smaller than the file size. You will have to trade off speed for progress indication here. You will probably want to make the chunks at least 1Mb to retain speed.